# How to clean the CO2 line?

Tags: kegging, cleaning, corny-keg

I had a tiny bit of backflow when I put the gasline back on the keg after force carbonation. It just flowed a tiny bit into the connector - nothing got inside the line itself.

I read [Backflow into gas line](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6512/backflow-into-gas-line), but it just tells me about the regulator.

What would be the prefered way of cleaning the line? The connector is giving me trouble, since I want to use my Beerline cleaner, but the connector is closed.

Any good Idea on how to clean the connector (Ball-lock)?

Comment: You should be able to disassemble the connector.   That slot at the top will take a medium-large flathead screwdriver.   Just keep on eye on where the spring goes...

Comment: @baka This should be in an answer

Comment: @baka That was the answer I was looking for. I saw the slot on the back of the connector, but I thought it might not be possible to open it without damaging it. I'll go for that I think. If you make that into an answer, it would be perfect ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--- edit update ---

Actually, I misspoke, I never use starsan (nothing against it) it is b-brite that I use as a soap.

--- original post follows ---

The next time you are cleaning, disconnect the line, and attach to to your auto siphon.

Use the siphon to push a bucket of soapy water through the line.  Then push some clean water through the line, then (because I'm paranoid) push an iodine solution through the line.  To dry, attach it to your CO2 and let the tank pressure push most of the water out.

If you time the cleaning of your line with other cleaning efforts, you don't even need to mix solutions.  Often I'll use the same soap (starsan for me) to do my keg, carboy, and lines at the same time.

One thing to keep in mind is that most lines are very inexpensive.  About 1/3 of the time, if my lines look nasty, I just undo the clamps and replace it.  Use properly sized automotive clamps, so a quick couple of turns with a screwdriver will have things apart before you know it.

Comment: Starsan isn't soap and won't do a good job removing debris. (Plus, running starsan and then iodine seems redundant.) Although I agree with you about just replacing cheap parts like lines.

Comment: Sorry, actually I run b-brite through the lines.  Was talking to my brother and he helped put "starsan" on my mind.  Actually, I don't even own any starsan, but I hear it can do good things.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to disassemble the connector. That slot at the top will take a medium-large flathead screwdriver. Just keep on eye on where the spring goes...